# Get next pointer of a row of a matrix

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a matrix of 1*5

I defined:

```
int **mat = new int*[5]; // define the matrix

int* ptr = *mat;
```

`ptr++` gives me the pointer of the next row of the matrix.

I want to get the pointer of the second element of the first row (the location of [0][1]).

how can I do it?

Comment: `(*ptr)+1`, or you do `ep = *ptr` then march through the elements of the row by `*ep++`.

Comment: The matrix elements should just be `mat[i][j]`, but you must first allocate memory for each row...

Comment: You say that you want a 1X5 matrix, so you should have only 1 row. How can you access the next row when you use `ptr++`? If you try to access it, it will be a seg fault. You should try and post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: If the matrix is 1x5,  why not a simple `int*` then ?

Comment: You better say what do you want to do. Because how you want to do this doesn't look right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C and C++ have no multi-dimensional arrays.  So to do this, you'll have to do extra allocations:

First, allocate your memory:

```
int rows = 1;
int columns = 5;

int** mat = new int*[columns];
for(int i = 0; i < columns; ++i)
{
    mat[i] = new int[rows];
}
```

Index your matrix:

```
int x = 1; // Column number, x-movement
int y = 0; // Row number, y-movement
//mat[x][y] = ???;
```

Don't forget to free memory that you allocated:

```
for(int i = 0; i < columns; ++i)
{
    delete [] mat[i];
}
delete [] mat;
```

Or, use std::vector.  It's much easier to use and understand:

```
#include <vector>

int rows = 1;
int columns = 5;

std::vector<std::vector<int > > mat = std::vector<std::vector<int > >();
mat.resize(columns);
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    mat[i].resize(rows);
}

//mat[1][0] = 100;
```

Comment: Also, the pointer to the second element of the first row would be &mat[1][0]

Answer (score -1):

### IN MY CODE IT WORKED LIKE THIS(the previous code has a problem for #columns>3 and #rows>3 especially for double precision vectors

```
#include vector
int rows=1;
int columns=5;
std::vector<std::vector<int > > mat = std::vector<std::vector<int > >();
mat.resize(rows);
for(int i = 0; i <rows; ++i)
{
mat[i].resize(columns)
}
```

Comment: Please format your answer properly. Remove the bold formatting, remove the all caps, add space before parentheses, and indent your code...